# Why does a Spanish internet modem/router not require a DSL filter?

Tags: router, internet, adsl

TL;DR - Why does an internet router in Spain not require a DSL filter?

I am trying to set up an ADSL router in Spain.  After some trial and error (RTFM) I see that Spanish routers do not require a DSL filter between the wall socket and the device.  Only the telephones require a DSL filter:

[image: Diagram 1]

AFAIK, in the United Kingdom, both the phone and router require a DSL filter (or one filter with both phone/router attached via it)

[image: Diagram 2]

Could anyone please enlighten me as to why this is?  I had assumed that ADSL was the same in all European countries.  I guess that the routers might have built-in filters, but am hoping for an authoritative answer that may also highlight any infrastructure differences.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 3):

You only need to filter the connection to the telephone, the connection to the DSL router is not filtered.

The UK filter you show is just a splitter with a filter built in on the telephone side of the splitter. Whereas the Spanish one you have a splitter and a filter as two separate units.